# Повторный запрос данных от пользователя при неправильном вводе

Tags: python, python-3.x, модули, pyowm

Есть код, он рабочий, но мне нужно сделать проверку правильности написания города, т.е. когда вводишь неправильно город (с ошибкой или не существующий) он просил ввести заново, а так ошибку выдает

```
from pyowm import OWM

from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config       # блок для изменения языка на русский
config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'

owm = OWM('c920e1facb71d07020ecfbdfca252772', config_dict )
place = input("Введите город, в котором хотите узнать погоду: ")
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)  # выдает ошибку в этой строке
w = observation.weather

# print(w)  # для проверки общих сведений

st = w.detailed_status
t = w.temperature('celsius')["feels_like"]

print("В городе " + place + " сейчас " + str(st))  # вывод погоды
print("Температура " + str(t) + "°C")     # вывод температуры
```

[image: Ошибка в Pycharme]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение рекурсией:

```py
import pyowm

from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'
owm = pyowm.OWM('ТОКЕН', config_dict)
mgr = owm.weather_manager()


def get_weather(city):
    try:
        observation = mgr.weather_at_place(city)
    except pyowm.commons.exceptions.NotFoundError:
        return get_weather(input("Вы неверно ввели город, введите КОРРЕКТНОЕ название: "))
    return observation.weather, city


weather, city = get_weather(input("Введите город, в котором хотите узнать погоду: "))

st = weather.detailed_status
t = weather.temperature('celsius')["feels_like"]
print("В городе " + city + " сейчас " + str(st))
print("Температура " + str(t) + "°C")
```

Решение циклом:

```py
import pyowm

from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'
owm = pyowm.OWM('ТОКЕН', config_dict)
mgr = owm.weather_manager()

city = input("Введите город, в котором хотите узнать погоду: ")

all_ok = False
while not all_ok:
    try:
        observation = mgr.weather_at_place(city)
    except pyowm.commons.exceptions.NotFoundError:
        city = input("Вы неверно ввели город, введите КОРРЕКТНОЕ название: ")
    else:
        weather = observation.weather
        all_ok = True

st = weather.detailed_status
t = weather.temperature('celsius')["feels_like"]
print("В городе " + city + " сейчас " + str(st))
print("Температура " + str(t) + "°C")
```

Comment: Вообще, это решается обычным циклом. Рекурсия действительно нужна только для довольно специфических случаев, типа обхода дерева.

Comment: Прикрепил два варианта решения

Comment: Спасибо больше, циклом прям супер получилось